# what is aggregate function in sql?

Tags: sql

I have two queries both are working fine when they executed separately:

```
select distinct 
    style_ref 
from 
    tbl_Size 
where 
    order_ref='123'

select 
    sum(quantity) 
from 
    tbl_size 
where 
    order_ref='123'
```

But if I try to combine them it does not work

```
select distinct 
    style_ref, sum(quantity) 
from 
    tbl_size 
where 
    order_ref='123'
```

ERROR appears:

> Column 'tbl_Size.style_ref' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Remove `distinct` and add `style_ref` into `group by`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An aggregate function is one that combines several records into a single one. In your case, `SUM`. You're taking the sum, clearly, of more than one row at a time. Another example might be `AVG`, to get the average of several values.

You can't run aggregate functions, as your error says, alongside ungrouped columns, because that introduces multiple "layers" of data. In one row, you'd have something that described the entire dataset, and you'd have something else that described only a single record. This would be confusing, not to mention inefficient.

Rather than using `DISTINCT` in your example, you're probably looking to `GROUP BY` your column:

```
SELECT style_ref, sum(quantity)
FROM tbl_size
WHERE order_ref='123'
GROUP BY style_ref
```

This will group up every set of records, based on their `style_ref` value, then tell you the sum of the quantities. Thus, assuming your schema naming is accurate, it will tell you how many orders were present for each `style_ref`.

The above query is equivalent in meaning to the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT style_ref, (SELECT SUM(quantity)
                            FROM tbl_size AS B
                            WHERE B.order_ref = '123'
                                  AND B.style_ref = tbl_size.style_ref)
FROM tbl_size
WHERE order_ref = '123'
```

As you can see, the `GROUP BY` solution is much, much cleaner and better to use. But I included this just to describe what it returns in a arguably a bit more of a readable way. You can see here how the aggregate function (`SUM`) could be described as working on a separate plane from the `style_ref` column, so it'd be hard to combine those into a single one without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Bappy please mark this as an answer if it helped you, so people in the future with your question will be better able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate function is a function that returns **one** result for many rows - like `sum` in your example.
You can use them in conjunction with the `group by` clause in order to get one result per group:

```
select   style_ref, sum(quantity) 
from     tbl_size 
where    order_ref='123'
group by style_ref
```